# How do i use the fundamental theory of arithmetic to proof the nth root of a positive integer is irrational?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In this example i'll try to use the FTA to prove that the $\sqrt[3] {81}$ is irrational.

So first i say that $$\sqrt[3] 3 \times  \sqrt[3] {27} = \sqrt[3] {81}\implies \sqrt[3] 3 \times 3 = \sqrt[3] {81}$$

So now i only need to prove $\sqrt[3] 3$ is irrational

So first i assume $\sqrt[3] 3$ is rational. So i can express it as 
$\frac  pq$ where $p,q\in \mathbb Z$

Then i can say $3 = \frac {p^3}{q^3}\implies 3q^3=p^3$

Now $3x$ goes into $p^3$ so by the FTA $3$ goes into $p$. $p = 3(x^y)$

So now i can say $3^3$ goes into $p^3$.

This implies $3q^3 = 27p^3\implies q^3=9p^3=3^2p^3$

So now i dont know how else to use the FTA.

Comment: Your formulae are hard to read, please consider using the appropriate MathJax typesetting ( http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ).

Comment: You are nearly done.  As $q^3$ is divisible by $3$ we must have $3|q$, but then $\frac pq$ can't have been in least terms.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Since $q^3 = 3^2p^3$, $3$ divides $q^3$. Then $3$ must divide $q$ (since $3$ is prime, here you use the FTA).

We then have that, for an arbitrary representation $\frac{p}{q}$ of $\sqrt[3]{3}$, $3$ divides both $p$ and $q$. But this is impossible: if we have a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, we can always simplify it untill $a$ and $b$ have no more common factors.